# How to control a panel nested in JtabbedPane ?

Tags: java, swing, parent-child, jtabbedpane

I have a `MainJtabbedPane` which contains multiple `JtabbedPanes` each of the `JtabbedPanes` contain  **multiple** pannels.

I need to be able to access the pannels from the `MainJtabbedPane`.

```
JTabbedPane[] components = (JTabbedPane[]) Main_Tabbed_Panel.getComponents();

for(int i=0; i<components.length;i++)
{
for(int j=0;j<components[i].getTabCount();j++)
{
.....
}
}
```

Giving an **error** `java.awt.component cannot be cast to javax.swing.JtabbedPane`

Comment: Could you show us the full stack trace, and the relevant code to the stack trace?

Comment: Main_Tabbed_Panel.getComponents() is a `Component[]`, not `JTabbedPane[]`, so that's the casting error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
JTabbedPane[] components = (JTabbedPane[]) Main_Tabbed_Panel.getComponents();
```

The getComponents() method returns an array of Components. You can't just cast them to a JTabbedPane even if you know all the components will be an instance of JTabbedPane. You need to structure your code something like:

```
for(Component component: main_Tabbed_Panel.getComponents())
{
    if (component instanceof JTabbedPane)
    {
        JTabbedPane tabbePane = (JTabbedPane)component;

        // do something with the tabbed pane
    }
}
```

Also, follow Java naming conventions. Variable name should NOT start with an upper case character. (ie. "Main_Tabbed_Pane does not follow conventions).

Comment: `Variable name should NOT start with an upper case character` - unless its a constant :) +1 for pointing out convention and simplified algorithm

Comment: Thank you this worked fine and thanks for the convention issue

Answer (score 1):

Switch the `(JTabbedPane[])` cast to `(Component[])`. If you hover over the `getComponents()` method, you'll see it returns `Component[]`

If you want to convert that `Component[]` to `JTabbedPane[]`, you need to do it manually, as well as making sure to check for mistakes along the way (making sure its a JTabbedPane before adding it to a JTabbedPane[])

```
JTabbedPane[] panes = convertComponents(getComponents());

private JTabbedPane[] convertComponents(Component[] comps) {
    JTabbedPane[] panes = comps.length > 0? new JTabbedPane[comps.length] : null;
    if(panes != null)
        for(int i = 0; i < panes.length; i++) {
            if(comps[i] instanceof JTabbedPane)
            panes[i] = (JTabbedPane) comps[i];
        }
    return panes;
}
```

Although this isn't the most efficient, because for each item that isn't a JTabbedPane in getComponents(), there will be an empty spot in your JTabbedPane array, which you then have to clean up.

`JTabbedPane[] panes = comps.length > 0? new JTabbedPane[comps.length] : null;`

This first checks if the Component[] passed through the parameters has 1 or more spaces. If not, dont bother initializing with an instance.

`if(panes != null)`

Since theres a chance `panes` could initialize as `null`, we much check before trying to use it

`for(int i = 0; i < panes.length-1; i++) {`

Since `Component[] comps` and `JTabbedPane[] panes` have the same size, it doesn't matter which length you use, as long as we know how many times to loop.

`if(comps[i] instanceof JTabbedPane)`

This is what I meant where I said "if the component isn't a `JTabbedPane`, you will have a null space in your array". This will check if it's a `JTabbedPane` before putting it in our panes array. If not, it's ignored completely, and that space in `panes` is left as null

After the loop is complete, it will return the array we just made.

Comment: How will I get the Tab Count or length for the second loop?? this is my concern